# Image processing within range in Hugo

Tags: hugo, hugo-content-organization

I'm trying to apply some [image processing](https://gohugo.io/content-management/image-processing/) to an image I get from page's metadata. I have a range of posts and this works:

```html
{{ range sort (where .Site.Pages ".Params.layout" "playlist") ".Params.sort" }}
    <div class="w-full max-w-sm bg-gray-900 hover:bg-brand border border-gray-900 rounded-lg shadow">
        <a href="{{ .Params.permalink }}">
            <img class="rounded-t-lg" src='{{ .Params.cover }}' alt="{{ .Title }}" />
        </a>
        <div class="px-5 mt-4 pb-5 text-center">
             <span class="text-lg mt-8 text-gray-200">{{ .Params.description }}</span>  
        </div>
    </div>
{{ end }}
```

So, my image is available as `{{ .Params.cover }}`, but I can't quite nail the syntax to apply some processing to it. I can access the image URL like so:

```
{{ $image := resources.Get .Params.cover }}
<p>{{ $image }}</p>
```

I've tried resizing it in a couple of ways:

```html
<img class="rounded-t-lg" src='{{  $image.Resize "500x" }}' alt="{{ .Title }}" />
```

```html
<img class="rounded-t-lg" src='{{ with $image.Resize "500x" }}{{ . }}{{ end }}' alt="{{ .Title }}" />
```

I've also tried outside the `<img/>` element like so:

```html
{{ $image := resources.Get .Params.cover }}
{{ $image := $image.Resize "500x" }}
<p>{{ $image }}</p>
<a href="{{ .Params.permalink }}">
    <img class="rounded-t-lg" src='{{ $image }}' alt="{{ .Title }}" />
</a>
```

In all of these cases, image does get rendered and I get no errors from hugo, but at its original size (1080x1080), not 500x500. So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GetMatch](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-resources/?search-input=getmatch#methods) instead of Get.

```
{{ $image := resources.GetMatch .Params.cover }}
```

Additionally, you should make sure that the `assetDir` is set correctly (you can do so in your config):

```
assetDir: static
```

Source/more info: https://hugocodex.org/blog/resize-all-images/